# CheckBox is not changing to Checked

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkbox

I have some logic that is supposed to read whether a column in a database is supposed to be 1 or 0, representing true or false.

I've gone through it with the debugger and the if statement evaluates to true, so surely that would mean that the checkbox should appear to be checked?

```
int QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(ddQuestions.SelectedItem.Text);

using (SqlDataReader dr = SQLData.checkchkbx(QuestionID))
{
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string TRUEorFALSE = dr["TRUEorFALSE"].ToString();
            int trueorfalse = Convert.ToInt32(TRUEorFALSE);

            if (trueorfalse == 1)
            {
                chkbxAnswer1.Checked=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have any other code that affects the checkbox?

Comment: Nope, I've commented it out. So to resolve this I would remove it from the while loop and use a get set?
Cheers

Comment: I wouldn't say you need to remove the loop, I'm just saying that if it does evaluate to True then it should work, and user, your answer doesn't do anything different to the op's code where they state the if statement already *does* evaluate to true

Comment: @Bigtingz92 - Thats why then, because you haven't ran that line of code yet, you need to check it *after* that line of code

Comment: what is type of `TRUEorFALSE` in your DataBase? make sure it is `bit`.

Comment: @Sayse - I am, the first iteration it evaluates to True, but doesn't execute the if statement, then the second iteration it is False
@User2946329 - As it happens, it is `bit`, although performance isn't a huge issue at the moment

Comment: @Bigtingz92 - In your previous comment you stated you are hovering over the `.Checked` line, this will continue to show False until it has been ran, you can then check the value after it, the code you've shown shouldn't produce the issue you are having

Comment: this two line(`string TRUEorFALSE = dr["TRUEorFALSE"].ToString();
int trueorfalse = Convert.ToInt32(TRUEorFALSE);`) of your code has this error:"*Input string was not in a correct format*". with my answer you have not this error anymore(*I tested it*) but if your rest of your code has no problem.

Comment: did you try removing out all your conditionals and just set the checkbox;checked as true in your function and verified whether it is appearing as checked?

Comment: Rohith - Just followed your suggestion, yes it appears as checked.
@Sayse - Ok, I'm going to lunch now, see if anyone else has any ideas, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve it by changing the "1" in the if statement to "True", as follows

```
 using (SqlDataReader dr = SQLData.checkchkbx(QuestionID))
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string TRUEorFALSE = dr["TRUEorFALSE"].ToString();
                        if (TRUEorFALSE == "True")
                        {
                            chkbxAnswer1.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

For some reason (I still don't know why) somewhere, the TRUEorFALSE column in the database, despite being populated with 1s and 0s, returns "True"s and "False"s, which is kinda cool, but I have no idea why...